# Footnotes on wrong page if framed environment spans two pages

Tags: xetex, footnotes, framed

The footnotes in the following example should show on page 1, but they show on page two. What can I do?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{leftbar}
  \lipsum[1]
  Test.\footnotemark{}
  \lipsum[1]
  Test.\footnotemark{}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{leftbar}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-2} 
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{First footnotetext.}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Second footnotetext.}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx

Comment: The commands to insert the footnotes appear in the second page. Move the `footnotetext` command before the framed environment.